# Calling self-serv API flight offers price get error "38196 resource not found"

Tags: amadeus

I called the flight offer search API. It returned 8 flight offers. I then picked the first offer and called the flight offer price API. I got this error

> {     "errors": [         {             "code": 38196,             "title": "Resource not found",             "detail": "The targeted resource doesn't exist",             "status": 404         }     ] }

Can anyone let me know what is wrong with my code please? Thanks in advance.

```
confirmFlightOffer = @"{

 ""data"": {
   ""type"": ""flight-offers-pricing"",
   ""flightOffers"": [
    {
     ""type"": ""flight-offer"",
     ""id"": ""1"",
     ""source"": ""GDS"",
     ""instantTicketingRequired"": false,
     ""nonHomogeneous"": false,
     ""oneWay"": false,
     ""lastTicketingDate"": ""2020-06-06"",
     ""numberOfBookableSeats"": 9,
     ""itineraries"": [
       {
         ""duration"": ""PT1H35M"",
         ""segments"": [
           {
             ""departure"": {
               ""iataCode"": ""SYD"",
               ""terminal"": ""2"",
               ""at"": ""2020-06-14T13:20:00""
             },

             ""arrival"": {
               ""iataCode"": ""MEL"",
               ""terminal"": ""4"",
               ""at"": ""2020-06-14T14:55:00""
             },
             ""carrierCode"": ""JQ"",
             ""number"": ""513"",
             ""aircraft"": { ""code"": ""320"" },
             ""operating"": { ""carrierCode"": ""JQ"" },
             ""duration"": ""PT1H35M"",
             ""id"": ""22"",
             ""numberOfStops"": 0,
             ""blacklistedInEU"": false
           }
         ]
       }
     ],

     ""price"": {
       ""currency"": ""AUD"",
       ""total"": ""140.74"",
       ""base"": ""102.75"",
       ""fees"": [
         {
           ""amount"": ""0.00"",
           ""type"": ""SUPPLIER""
         },
         {
           ""amount"": ""0.00"",
           ""type"": ""TICKETING""
         }
       ],
       ""grandTotal"": ""140.74""
     },
     ""pricingOptions"": {
       ""fareType"": [ ""PUBLISHED"" ],
       ""includedCheckedBagsOnly"": true
     },
     ""validatingAirlineCodes"": [ ""HR"" ],
     ""travelerPricings"": [
       {
         ""travelerId"": ""1"",
         ""fareOption"": ""STANDARD"",
         ""travelerType"": ""ADULT"",
         ""price"": {
           ""currency"": ""AUD"",
           ""total"": ""140.74"",
           ""base"": ""102.75""
         },
         ""fareDetailsBySegment"": [
           {
             ""segmentId"": ""22"",
             ""cabin"": ""ECONOMY"",
             ""fareBasis"": ""HLOW"",
             ""class"": ""H"",
             ""includedCheckedBags"": {
               ""weight"": 20,
               ""weightUnit"": ""KG""
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ]
 }
}";


           var client = new RestClient(_apiUrl);
           client.Timeout = -1;
           var request = new RestRequest("​/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing", Method.POST);  
           request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {_token}");
           request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
           request.AddParameter("application/json", confirmFlightOffer, ParameterType.RequestBody);
           var response = client.Execute<ConfirmFlightOfferResponse>(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

This works

```
 var client = new RestClient(_apiUrl + "/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing");
 client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
```

but this doesn't

```
 var client = new RestClient(_apiUrl);
 client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest("/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing",Method.POST);
```

Don't know why.